# Unable to customise Plank on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, plank

folks!
I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 on my Asus 1015-CX. In my case, it's smoother than the previous version, but I am not able to customise Plank any more by rightclicking on the dock, which I could with the previous version of the distro.

Any idea why this is not possible any more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain? i.e. No menu? No option? - I use Plank and hsve the customization options. Do you have the Plank dock icon enabled?

Comment: The issue was Ctrl+Rightclick. I didn't press Ctrl.

Answer (score 1):

While pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, right-click on the mouse or touchpad then choose *Preferences*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! It works now.
However, another issue has just come up. When Plank is active, a line appears on my screen. If I kill the Plank process, it disappears. Any suggestion?

Comment: @vasqu1nho: If you have a new question please [open a new question](/questions/ask). Comments are not meant for larger follow-up questions or extended discussion.

Comment: +1 because this answer is valid for recent releases of Plank, regardless of Ubuntu releases. Tested working with Plank 0.11.1.1551 Development on Xubuntu 14.04.